# Прямая трансляция.

Tags: ajax, javascript, php, html, css

На сайте - http://chesstv.com/ru есть прямая трансляция. Я хочу, что бы эта трансляция отображалась у меня на сайте(т.е. не вся страница http://chesstv.com/ru, а только трансляция)Т.е. что бы пользователь кликал у меня на сайте по ссылке и ему открывалась бы трансляция с  http://chesstv.com/ru. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать, и можно ли вообще это сделать? Желательно описать общий поход к решению этой задачи, т.к. в сети много интернет каналов, и я хочу всех их к себе на сайт перетащить.

Answer (score 1):

Встройте видео аналогично тому, как оно встроено на указанном вами сайте

```
<div id="digicast_player">
    <iframe 
        name="easyXDM_default7258_provider" 
        id="easyXDM_default7258_provider" 
        src="http://live.digicast.ru/embed/1643?language=ru&amp;params%5Bext_css%5D=chess_index_player&amp;params%5Bext_js%5D=chess_player&amp;params%5Bph%5D=390&amp;params%5Bpw%5D=733&amp;params%5Bwmode%5D=opaque&amp;xdm_e=http%3A%2F%2Fchesstv.com&amp;xdm_c=default7258&amp;xdm_p=1" 
        frameborder="0" 
        style="height: 496px; width: 100%;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```